# precondition, postcondition and return value

Tags: debugging

I was reading in "think python" book, and I read chapter 6.9 that talks about debugging.

Breaking a large program into smaller functions creates natural checkpoints for debugging. If a function is not working, there are three possibilities to consider:

There is something wrong with the arguments the function is getting; a precondition is violated.
There is something wrong with the function; a postcondition is violated.
There is something wrong with the return value or the way it is being used.

I understood what it means, but I tried to make examples so I can understand better and I couldn't.
Can anyone give me simple examples, so I can understand it better?

Comment: This is not specific to a language, but generic programming thing. Common way to check for these in use `assert` statements, which you use to ensure that internal logic is valid. For example, rather than commenting `# first arg foo must not be None` it's maybe better to write `assert foo is not None`. 

Some languages have pre- and postconditions builtin, like Eiffel. For others, you can use either just assert, property-based testing or libraries like https://andreacensi.github.io/contracts/. For debugging though, assert is just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this terminology, but I guess I can understand what he meant.

Let's take a small function for example:

```py
def mystery(num1, num2):
    new_num = num1 / num2
    is_square = True
    if new_num == num2:
        is_square = True
    return is_square
```

This function first divides `num1` by `num2`, then checks if the result is the as `num2` (aka num2^2 = num1) and return `is_square`. It's not the most efficient of course to check if it's square, but it fits for our purpose.

What can be wrong with the arguments of the function?
I assume in my code that `num2` is a number (and not string) and that it is not zero. "Something wrong with the arguments" means that someone calls the function with a string or zero or anything else which is not valid. It's an error.

Secondly, and error within the function: notice I made a mistake (on purpose) and `is_square` should be initialized to False. This is an example of an error of the function.

The last kind of error, something with the return value - is if you return a wrong value, like returns `num1` instead of `is_square`, return `not is_square` (the opposite) and etc.